# get result in hindi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I am developing an app where I have some text views. One text view shows default language like English and another text view shows same text in another text style like Arabic, Flamer Style etc. For this I used .ttf files but now, I want to change that text in Hindi font style. I want that text like "`sudha`" as "`सुधा`". How can I do this.

If someone has an idea about it please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sudha you can try this one:

```
@autoreleasepool{ // text view code here 
    [textViewAbout setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"NewFont" size:24]];
}
```